# How to add an item at a random position in an array, javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have an array `var arr = [1,2,3,4,5]` and I want to add `x` at a random position in the array.

I tried this

```
let n = arr.length;
let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
for (let i = randomIndex; i < n + 1; i++) {
    arr[i+1] = arr[i];
    arr[randomIndex] = 'x';
}
```

The expected output after calling the function above was [1,2,'x',3,4,5] or ['x',1,2,3,4,5] or [1,2,3,4,'x',5]
But it didn't work. Any suggestion would help

Comment: `splice` method ... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Comment: You are copying whatever is at originally at 'randomIndex' into the rest of the array.   your original array for example you are setting arr[3] to arr[2], then arr[4] to arr[3], then arr[5] to arr[4].  And each time you are setting arr[2] to 'x', you only need to do that once.  For small loops, it can help if you actually work out each step on paper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `splice` to insert at at particular position. The idiom `| 0` is equivalent to `Math.floor()` for positive numbers less than `2^31`.

Note that you need to use `arr.length+1` to ensure that one of the possible the random positions can be after the last element of the original array.

```js
const arr = [1,2,3,4,5]

arr.splice((arr.length+1) * Math.random() | 0, 0, 'x')

console.log(arr)
```

Comment: Why bother with the bitwise int cast though? `const { floor, random } = Math;` if you don't want Math prefixes everywhere, but flooring instead of an operation that doesn't work for almost half of the valid Number range is always nicer (yeah it's a neat trick, but 99.99% of the time also completely unnecessary =)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans the maximum array size in Javascript is `2^32-2`, but using `|0` will only work up to `2^31-1`. I personally prefer to write tighter code with fewer brackets where I can, if I know I'm not dealing with huge amounts of data.

Answer (score 0):

```js
let arr = ['apple', 'pear', 'banana'];
arr[Math.floor(Math.random()*arr.length)]='tomato';
console.log(arr);
//tomato is not a fruit
```

Comment: This change random array item value, not adding an item  to random position

Comment: sorry, I misnderstood the question. However, I see a few answers that are sufficient already.

Answer (score 0):

It Should work perfectly.

```js
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let n = arr.length;
let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * (n + 1)); // generate random index including the end of the array

arr.splice(randomIndex, 0, 'x'); // insert 'x' at random index

for (let i = n - 1; i > 0; i--) {
  let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1)); // generate random index to swap with
  [arr[i], arr[j]] = [arr[j], arr[i]]; // swap elements at indices i and j
}

console.log(arr); // Output
```